# Async and non blocking SOAP server

Tags: java, asynchronous, soap, nonblocking

We've played with async and non blocking with spring doing stuff like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/async")
public Callable<String> processUpload(final MultipartFile file) {

    return new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(2000)
            return "someView";
        }
    };

}
```

It runs very fast indeed ([spring boot java 8 + tomcat 8](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-async))

Problem is taht we want to do it also with SOAP webservices  and here we find very little page about it.
I've found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241712/non-blocking-ws-call-with-cxf) but it is for async client I think

Any way to do this in cxf jaxws or others?